# trouble using HERE Mobile SDK UI Kit

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to implement new HERE Mobile SDK UI Kit for Android but with no luck.
did everything described in Quickstart text file inside **uikit-android-release-1.0.0-78**. During gradle compiling 
there is no error only when application launched. Pasting logcat errors.

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       ...................................... 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration;
        at com.here.msdkui.routing.WaypointList.init(WaypointList.java:48)
        at com.here.msdkui.routing.WaypointList.<init>(WaypointList.java:35)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
       ......................................
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration" 
 on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.testapp.nav-1/base.apk", 
 zip file "/data/app/com.testapp.nav-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", 
 zip file "/data/app/com.testapp.nav-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", 
 zip file "/data/app/com.testapp.nav-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", 
..................................................................
 zip file "/data/app/com.testapp.nav-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
 nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.testapp.nav-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClas
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the [android support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) in your build?

Seems like you are missing it!